# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'(school assignment)

Tags: python

This is my school homework which i have to submit tomorrow, any experts who can help me out

```
#replacing all value greater than 10 to 10
while True:
    n=list(input("Enter Your Number:-"))
    z=int(input("Do You Want To Continue?(1-Yes/2-No)"))
    if z==2:
        break
    else:
        continue
for i in range(len(n)):
    if n[i] > 10:
        n[i] = 10
print(n)
```

Comment: Is getting the answer to your homework from a stranger on the internet acceptable to your teacher/prof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert it into int by using the `int()` function

```
#replacing all value greater than 10 to 10
while True:
    n=list(input("Enter Your Number:-"))
    z=int(input("Do You Want To Continue?(1-Yes/2-No)"))
    if z==2:
        break
    else:
        continue
for i in range(len(n)):
    if int(n[i]) > 10: # here I changed / convert into int()
        n[i] = 10
print(n)
```

then there will be no errors

Answer (score 0):

Add this line before the `for` loop:

```
n = [int(elem) for elem in n]
```

Full code:

```
while True:
    n=list(input("Enter Your Number:-"))
    z=int(input("Do You Want To Continue?(1-Yes/2-No)"))
    if z==2:
        break
    else:
        continue
n = [int(elem) for elem in n]
for i in range(len(n)):
    if n[i] > 10:
        n[i] = 10
print(n)
```